# How can I neaten up SQL*Plus layout?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Apologies, I am new to Oracle and SQL in general.

Is there any way to neaten up the appearance of my SQL*Plus output so that each header is underlined, rather than output all the headers then the lines as shown?

[image]

Comment: Each header *is* underlined. The problem is that the text is wrapped due to `linesize` and terminal width.

Comment: @William Robertson - Any recommendations on how to neaten it up?

Comment: I think the answers already posted about cover it, although I would also look at the terminal width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET LINESIZE 3000
```

before the query.

One more option you can do is:

```
SET WRAP OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your window wide enough to fit all the columns in one line, then you need to tell Sql*plus to format it’s results with that line size.
Eg

```
Set linesize 400
```

You can also modify the size it gives certain columns by formatting the column

```
Col custaddress for a30
```

Other useful settings are pagesize (to control how many lines to show before repeating the header, the default is very low), tab (this can be on or off, on will cause some of your results to appear off centre every now and then)

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQLPlus formatting question. This utility offers various formatting options, that are detailed [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/formatting-SQL-Plus-reports.html).

Common options are:

- set the maximum size of a line, in characters:

```
    set linesize 180
    -- do not set a linesize wider than your terminal size!
```

- set the size of each column in the resultset:

```
    column mycol format a50
```